# Magento 2 How to override Protected Function

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override a block function in `_createWishlistItemCollection` located in folder `/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBlock.php`

I have used the plugin method to override the block method.

This is my **di.xml** file (**/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**)

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Send" type=Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Send"/>
<type name="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items">
    <plugin name="multiwishlistsharewishlist"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Share\Email\Items"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Wishlist">
    <plugin name="mwsharewishlist"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Share\Wishlist"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Then I created a file in **/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Share/Email/Items.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Share\Email;

class Items
{
    /**
     * Create wishlist item collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection
     */


    public function beforeCreateWishlistItemCollection()    {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/wishlist1.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');
    }


}
```

The controller file **Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Send.php** is below:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Session\Generic as WishlistSession;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout as ResultLayout;

class Send extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Send
{
    public function execute()
    {

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $wishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist();
        if (!$wishlist) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }

        $sharingLimit = $this->_wishlistConfig->getSharingEmailLimit();
        $textLimit = $this->_wishlistConfig->getSharingTextLimit();
        $emailsLeft = $sharingLimit - $wishlist->getShared();

        $emails = $this->getRequest()->getPost('emails');
        $emails = empty($emails) ? $emails : explode(',', $emails);

        $error = false;
        $message = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('message');
        if (strlen($message) > $textLimit) {
            $error = __('Message length must not exceed %1 symbols', $textLimit);
        } else {
            $message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($message));
            if (empty($emails)) {
                $error = __('Please enter an email address.');
            } else {
                if (count($emails) > $emailsLeft) {
                    $error = __('This wish list can be shared %1 more times.', $emailsLeft);
                } else {
                    foreach ($emails as $index => $email) {
                        $email = trim($email);
                        if (!\Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                            $error = __('Please enter a valid email address.');
                            break;
                        }
                        $emails[$index] = $email;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($error) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($error);
            $this->wishlistSession->setSharingForm($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/share');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
//$mid = $this->getRequest()->getPost('multiwishlist_id');echo "test".$mid;exit;
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout */
        $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
        $this->addLayoutHandles($resultLayout);
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $sent = 0;

        try {
            $customer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject();
            $customerName = $this->_customerHelperView->getCustomerName($customer);

            $message .= $this->getRssLink($wishlist->getId(), $resultLayout);
            $emails = array_unique($emails);
            $sharingCode = $wishlist->getSharingCode();

            try {

                foreach ($emails as $email) {
                    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
                        $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            'wishlist/email/email_template',
                            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        )
                    )->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(),
                        ]
                    )->setTemplateVars(
                        [
                            'customer' => $customer,
                            'customerName' => $customerName,
                            'salable' => $wishlist->isSalable() ? 'yes' : '',
                            'items' => $this->getWishlistItems($resultLayout),
                            'viewOnSiteLink' => $this->_url->getUrl('*/shared/index', ['code' => $sharingCode]),
                            'message' => $message,
                            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
                        ]
                    )->setFrom(
                        $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            'wishlist/email/email_identity',
                            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        )
                    )->addTo(
                        $email
                    )->getTransport();

                    $transport->sendMessage();

                    $sent++;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $wishlist->setShared($wishlist->getShared() + $sent);
                $wishlist->save();
                throw $e;
            }
            $wishlist->setShared($wishlist->getShared() + $sent);
            $wishlist->save();

            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch('wishlist_share', ['wishlist' => $wishlist]);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Your wish list has been shared.'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*', ['wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()]);
            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->wishlistSession->setSharingForm($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/share');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare to load additional email blocks
     *
     * Add 'wishlist_email_rss' layout handle.
     * Add 'wishlist_email_items' layout handle.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addLayoutHandles(ResultLayout $resultLayout)
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('rss_url')) {
            $resultLayout->addHandle('wishlist_email_rss');
        }
        $resultLayout->addHandle('wishlist_email_items');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve RSS link content (html)
     *
     * @param int $wishlistId
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getRssLink($wishlistId, ResultLayout $resultLayout)
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('rss_url')) {
            return $resultLayout->getLayout()
                ->getBlock('wishlist.email.rss')
                ->setWishlistId($wishlistId)
                ->toHtml();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve wishlist items content (html)
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getWishlistItems(ResultLayout $resultLayout)
    {

$mid = $this->getRequest()->getPost('multiwishlist_id');
        return $resultLayout->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('wishlist.email.items')
->setMid($mid)
            ->toHtml();
    }
}
```

But the block function is not getting overrided and the log value is not getting.

Answer (score 11):

**Plugins cannot be used with non-public method**: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html.
In your case, we should use Preference to override these classes: `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items`, `Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Wishlist`.

*Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items" 
    type="Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email\Items"/>
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Wishlist" 
    type="Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Wishlist"/>
```

*Vendor/Module/Block/Share/Email/Items.php*

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Share\Email;

classe Items extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items
{
     protected function _createWishlistItemCollection() {
       ......
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly this for protected function `_prepareLayout()` in `CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php`, but it's not working. Anyone get this working? I can, however, successfully override non-protected functions such as `getSearchQueryText()` just fine.

Comment: trying to override _prepareLayout() function of module-customer\Block\Address\Book.php. Not working ..

Comment: @thdoan did you got solution

Comment: if(!$this->helper->getStatus()){
   return parent::method();
  }
If we want to call the parent method based on the store settings , how can we do that

Answer (score -1):

Please create a custom module and follow below steps:

Step1 :- Go to

Custom Vendor Name/Custom Module Name/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items" type="Custom Vendor Name\Custom Module Name\Block\Share\Email\Items"/>
</config>
```

Step2 :- Go to

Custom Vendor Name/Custom Module Name/Block/Share/Email/Items.php

```
namespace Custom Vendor Name\Custom Module Name\Block\Share\Email;

class Items extends \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Share\Email\Items
{
     protected function _createWishlistItemCollection() {
      //put your code
    }
}
```