# Magento 2 - How to call a protected function from the subject inside a plugin

Tags: magento2, override-model, after-plugin

I have created a plugin for a particular function. That function is also calling another `protected` function of the core file.

```
public function afterPopulateTaxRateData(
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate\Converter $subject,
    $result,
    $formData
) {
    if ($this->_helper->isEnable()) {
        if (isset($formData['zip_is_range']) && $formData['zip_is_range']) {
            if ($this->_helper->isRangeEnable()) {
                $result->setTaxCity($this->extractFormData($formData, 'tax_city'));
            } else {
                $result->setTaxCity("");
            }
        } else {
            $result->setTaxCity($this->extractFormData($formData, 'tax_city'));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

How to call the `protected` function `extractFormData` inside this plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to call `$subject->extractFormData()`. Hope this will work

Comment: Copy `extractFormData` function from the core and put it in your plugin or else use `$subject->extractFormData()` and check it.

Comment: I used $subject->extractFormData() .But it throws .....Uncaught Error: Call to protected method Magento\\Tax\\Model\\Calculation\\Rate\\Converter::extractFormData() from context 'XXX\\YYY\\Plugin\\Converter' in /var/www/html/magento231/app/code/XXX/YYY/Plugin/Converter.php:50

Comment: Copy `extractFormData` function from the core and put it in your plugin and check it.

Comment: Yes. I used that. But, Magento returns duplicate code is there.

Comment: @Dhaduk It returns .....The file Converter.php is too similar to the Magento2 file - magento/module-tax/magento-module-tax-100.3.0-beta32/Model/Calculation/Rate/Converter.php
- since this file edits public functions,
you can avoid duplicating code using Magento 2's plugin structure: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150797/magento-2-how-to-override-protected-function. See `Khoa TruongDinh` answer.