# How to override protected method of Abstract class in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4

I am trying to override protected method `_saveValidatedBunches()` of abstract class `Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity`, I have tried creating `preference` for parent class but its not working. Is there any way to override.

**Module/Model/Import/Customclass**

```
class Customclass extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity
{ public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Helper\Data $importExportData,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data $importData,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface $errorAggregator
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_importExportData = $importExportData;
        $this->_resourceHelper = $resourceHelper;
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->errorAggregator = $errorAggregator;
        foreach ($this->errorMessageTemplates as $errorCode => $message) {
            $this->getErrorAggregator()->addErrorMessageTemplate($errorCode, $message);
        }
        $entityType = $config->getEntityType($this->getEntityTypeCode());
        $this->_entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();
        $this->_dataSourceModel = $importData;
        $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection();
    } protected function _importData()
     {
        parent::_importData();
     } protected function _saveValidatedBunches()
    {
        die("Die Here");
    }
    Other abstract method of core class are define in this class with its parent method like `_importData()`
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Firebear\ImportExport\Model\Import\CartPriceRule" type="Override\Module\Model\Import\Customclass"/>
  <preference for="Magento\AdvancedPricingImportExport\Model\Import\AdvancedPricing" type="Override\Module\Model\Import\Customclass"/>
  <preference for="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product" type="Override\Module\Model\Import\Customclass"/>
  <preference for="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Option" type="Override\Module\Model\Import\Customclass"/>
</config>
```

Comment: Overwrite all child class.

Comment: we already override all child classes but this issue is not resloved

Comment: Error Code - 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Show your code example

Comment: you can't overwrite an abstract class. Abstract classes are loaded because they are extended from by the classes themselves and not handled through the Magento DI handler.

Comment: Question update

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150797/magento-2-how-to-override-protected-function

Comment: Should not be overridden, but should create a reference to the creator pattern